# elasticsearch: Import data from sql using c#

Tags: import, insert, load, elasticsearch, bulk

can anyone give me some directions / examples about how to import about 100 million rows from SQL server to Elasticsearch using c# language?

Currently I'm using a NEST client in c# but is very slow ( 5k - 10k / Minute ), the slowness looks like is more from the app side than ES.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Could you provide (parts of) the code that you are currently using?

Comment: @Alejandro You should use IndexMany method. client.IndexMany(buffer);

Answer (score 0):

You can use IndexMany but if you want to index only one table I think you can try with JDBC plugin. After [installation](http://hintdesk.com/how-to-connect-elasticsearch-to-ms-sql-server/), you can simply execute a .bat script to index your table.

```
@echo off

set DIR=%~dp0
set LIB=%DIR%..\lib\*
set BIN=%DIR%..\bin

REM ???
echo {^
"type" : "jdbc",^
"jdbc" : {^
"url" : "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:25488;instanceName=SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=AdventureWorks2014",^
"user" : "hintdesk",^
"password" : "123456",^
"sql" : "SELECT BusinessEntityID as _id, BusinessEntityID, Title, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName FROM Person.Person",^
"treat_binary_as_string" : true,^
"elasticsearch" : {^
"cluster" : "elasticsearch",^
"host" : "localhost",^
"port" : 9200^
},^
"index" : "person",^
"type" : "person"^
}^
}^ | "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -cp "%LIB%" -Dlog4j.configurationFile="%BIN%\log4j2.xml" "org.xbib.tools.Runner" "org.xbib.tools.JDBCImporter"
```